# cassandra.cluster with pyinstaller not working

Tags: python, cassandra

I am trying to create executable using pyinstaller on my Mac for a simple python file TestAudit.py, which contains

`from cassandra.cluster import Cluster`

And getting below error when I run my executable:

```
TestAudit.py:7: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from
'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestAudit.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 23, in init cassandra.cluster
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'concurrent'
[46470] Failed to execute script TestAudit
```

My Python version is Python 3.7.3
Mac: MacOS High Sierra, Version 10.13.6

Please help if anybody knows how to fix this, Or else how can we package TestAudit.py along with dependencies ?

TestAudit.py file:

```
"""Program to initialze Cassandra driver"""
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from datetime import datetime
print("now =", datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to add every missing module to the [hiddenimports](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) of pyinstaller and run the executable again until no more missing modules were found.

After compiling an executable with pyInstaller, you will notice a *.spec file inside your directory. There, you can add the modules to the hiddenimports list and run `pyInstaller <yourModule>.spec` to build the executable again.

Here's the list of missing modules that I found for my case:

```
hiddenimports=['concurrent', 'concurrent.futures', 'json', 'cassandra.connection', 'cassandra.marshal', 'cassandra.protocol', 'cassandra.type_codes', 'geomet.wkt', 'cassandra.compat', 'cassandra.cython_deps', 'cassandra.pool', 'cassandra.policies', 'cassandra.timestamps', 'cassandra.datastax', 'cassandra.datastax.insights', 'cassandra.datastax.insights.reporter', 'cassandra.datastax.cloud', 'cassandra.io', 'cassandra.io.asyncorereactor']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

1. Move cluster.py to the same folder as your TestAudit.py
2. Change the reference in your code to remove the 'cassandra' subfolder
3. Run pyinstaller again

Comment: After copying cluster.py and changing code as mentioned above to `from cluster import Cluster`  I get another error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestAudit.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "cluster.py", line 48, in <module>
  File "cassandra/connection.py", line 41, in init cassandra.connection
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cassandra.marshal'
[81867] Failed to execute script TestAudit`

Comment: Also tried copying marshal.py to the same folder as TestAudit.py. Getting same error as above.